# python-requests cookies export session to selenium

Tags: python, session, selenium, cookies, python-requests

I want to export cookies session from python-requests to selenium, im write this code :

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

session=requests.Session()

MyHeaderss = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.32 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.32", "X-GWT-Permutation" : "6FEFBE57C6E73F0AB33BD5A4E17945DE", "Content-Type":"text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8"}

login_data = '''7|0|7|https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/|FEAC78FFDF81D6121438D70986AF1C41|portale.titolari.client.service.PTService|login|portale.titolari.client.common.login.LoginRequest/3583069702|xxxxxxxxxxx|matteosbragia1984|1|2|3|4|1|5|5|0|0|6|7|'''


ra0=session.post('https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/service', data=login_data, headers=MyHeaderss)
print ra0.content

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.32 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.32")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

for c in session.cookies :
    driver.add_cookie({'name': c.name, 'value': c.value, 'path': c.path, 'expiry': c.expires})


print "dasdasds"
driver.get("https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/titolari.html#H6VwDv5Ce0")
print "dasdasds2"
driver.get("https://www.cartetitolari.mps.it/portaleTitolari/downloadeco?id=0")
```

The code work, but not successfully export session/cookies in selenium, when the page loads are required to login! Where I'm wrong ?

Comment: You need to navigate to the page to set the domain before calling `add_cookie`.

Comment: im try bat not work, same problem the session not transfer

Comment: Do you have the same cookies between a manual and an automated session?

Comment: the cookies is generate automated whit python-requests ... api login

Comment: try to use `selenium-requests` module for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are not floating around in the browser preferences. They are always tied to a specific domain or a wildcard domain, but they always have a domain.

Have a look at [selenium-requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium-requests/) package which seems to ease the creation of the cookies.